# How to perform child displacement on 3D object, Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Here I have a simple example of an object being loaded using `MTLLoader()` and `OBJLoader()` in Three.js

```
var loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
loader.load(<?php echo "'".$mPart."'"; ?>, function (materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoaderOfficeChair = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoaderOfficeChair.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoaderOfficeChair.load(<?php echo "'".$oPart."'"; ?>, function (object) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ){
                x=document.getElementsByClassName("popup");  
                   for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                      x[i].innerHTML += "<li class='mi_child'>"+child.name+"</li>";    
                    var timer = performance.now();
                    geometry = child.geometry;
                    geometry.dynamic = true;
                    material = child.material;
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    model = object.children[i].geometry;
                    model2 = object;  
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    }
```

Now later in the anim() code, I call another action which will move the children the object loaded. Now I would like these items to be moved in all different directions.

```
var center = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var distanceToMove = 0.1;
if(params.explodeEnabled)  {
for (var i = 0; i < model2.children.length; i++) {
   model2.children[i].position.x =  explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * i;
   model2.children[i].position.y = explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * i - 0.02;
   model2.children[i].position.z =  explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * i + 0.06;
}
}
```

But in this example all the items move together in the same direction as seen here. 
[More Info](http://ustarp.com/3DModels/?part=04c32d4d95425f73b3a1d6502aed4d48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move each part along a different path from the center of the object. Save the old position of each part, and calculate its direction away from the center.

```
var explosionCenter = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < model2.children.length; i++) {
    var child = model2.children[i];

    if (!child.geometry.boundingSphere) child.computeBoundingSphere();

    child.oldPosition = child.oldPosition || geometry.boundingSphere.center.clone();
    var direction = child.oldPosition.clone().sub(explosionCenter).normalize(); 

    child.position.x = child.oldPosition.x + explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * direction.x;
    child.position.y = child.oldPosition.y + explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * direction.y;
    child.position.z = child.oldPosition.z + explodeValue + outlinePass.Explode * direction.z;
}
```

This way, each component will move away from the center depending on its initial position. You should use custom direction vectors for some of the big components to make sure they do not cover the small ones:

```
if (i == <index of big component>) {
    direction = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0); // Custom direction for a component 
}
```

Comment: This made is so each part doesn't move at all.

Comment: I'' select as anwser as soon as you upgreat the code to work

Comment: How about now? I have changed the code to save the old position before exploding. @StevenHammons

Comment: No, sorry doesn't do anything at all. No movement

Comment: Here is example of your code at work http://ustarp.com/3DModels/?part=04c32d4d95425f73b3a1d6502aed4d48       Remember to use explodeEnabled on controls

Comment: Ah, I will look at this after the weekend. I am sure we can make it work in the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure what's going on with it maybe the way i'm setting the explode value or something

Comment: Direction is coming out null

Comment: Anybody shine some light on this ?

Comment: Hello! Back from a weekend at the cabin. I have looked at the running code you posted, and I see that each part is positioned at (0,0,0). This was not my assumption. I have fixed the code now, so that it uses the geometric center of each part instead. Try it now!

Comment: By the way, if you look in the js console, there are a lot of errors in your existing code. This might interfere with the explosion code.

Comment: Great job, they do move in the right direction now.